# If A is matrix of k*k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is matrix of $k\times k$ , then is it necessary that $Ax, A^2x , A^3x ...... A^kx$   will be linearly dependent ? $x$ is a vector and $A$ contains all real entries

Comment: Try to use Tex. What is Ax^2, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. Take $A=I_n$, the identity matrix. It is true, if $A^{k+1}=0$, but $A^k\neq 0$, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916533/prove-that-the-set-left-x-ax-dots-ak-1-x-right-is-linearly-indepe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. For example:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$x=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
So:
$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$A^2x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$A^3x=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
And they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

No, take any matrix $A\in \mathcal{M}_k(\mathbb{R})$ which is idempotent in the sense that  $A^2=A$. That is, any projection matrix (including $I_k$, the $k\times k$ identity matrix) does not have this property.