# Linear independence of a family of nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is a nilpotent matrix for 3 (i.e. A^2 ≠ 0 and A^3=0), how to show that (I, A, A^2) is linearly independent?

I had the idea of choosing a, b, and c as three real numbers such that aI + bA + cA^2 = 0 and then show that they’re equal to zero, but I don’t know how to do that.

(Not sure of the accuracy of terms. English is not my first language.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, that’s what I meant. I wasn’t sure what to call “indice de nilpotence” in English. Could you please prove the result?

Comment: Multiply by $A^2$. Then start again and multiply by $A$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician oh wow that was obvious. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See proof works in the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916533/prove-that-the-set-left-x-ax-dots-ak-1-x-right-is-linearly-indepe?noredirect=1&lq=1).